# Can I run an uppercase method on an object?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object. Is there a way to run toUppercase on all of its keys?
What I'm doing is trying to uppercase every element in this object

```
JSON.stringify(JSONObj.people).toUpperCase()
```

I haven't gotten the above command to work for me. I'm a bit new to this, so appreciate any help!

Comment: can you tell me me exact JSONObj value you get in that place,,so that we can separate key and value

Comment: {"John Smith":25,"Jane Doe":46,"Ben Franklin":32}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Object.withUpperCaseKeys = function upperCaseKeys(o) {
// this solution ignores inherited properties
    var r = {};
    for (var p in o)
        r[p.toUpperCase()] = o[p];
    return r;
}
```

Use this method to create a *new* object with different keys:

```
JSONObj.people = Object.withUpperCaseKeys(JSONObj.people);
```

If you want to change an object (modify the instance), use

```
Object.upperCaseKeys = function upperCaseKeys(o) {
// this solution ignores inherited properties
    for (var p in o)
        if (p.toUpperCase() != p) {
            o[p.toUpperCase()] = o[p];
            delete o[p];
        }
    return o; // just for easier chaining
}

Object.upperCaseKeys(JSONObj.people);
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove the original items.

Comment: It's OK, I should have made this clear. I've edited my post to show the difference.

Comment: Hi, Small error though.  p[p.toUpperCase()] = o[p]; >>>> should be >>>  o[p.toUpperCase()] = o[p];